# visual studio 2022 gets hang when i try to edit _layout.cshtml file, its ok with other cshtml files edit

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

visual studio 2022 gets hang when I try to edit _layout cshtml file, its ok with other cshtml files edit. I tried every thing from resetting it, uninstall and then reinstall .anyone having idea what's wrong.
I am using asp.net core MVC with Dot Net 6.

Comment: You can try to create a new project. If this problem still occurs, you can report this issue directly in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, actually there was problem with my windows auto update, so I reinstall the windows 10 and then installed visual studio 2022.